# IntelliJ - impose try\catch on code throwing exceptions

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In eclipse, the framework imposes try\catch or throws statements on any code which throws exceptions. You cannot continue without doing something with the exception.

For example, if you'd write:

```
File propertiesFile = new File(PROPS_FILE_PATH)
```

Eclipse wouldn't build the project unless you surrounded it with **try/catch** or added **throws FileNotFoundException** to the method signature.

IntelliJ does not impose that.

Is there any parallel behavior in IntelliJ? Any plugin?

---

Guys, thank you all for your advises. 
My main concern was to understand if there is a way to achieve the same behavior of "detecting and alerting of exceptions" like in the Eclipse IDE.

---

Following the locking of my question:

As described on [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/handling-exceptions-java-using):

> When creating an Exception class, the programmer **has to designate** a
>   kind of exception that must be caught or optionally caught. If you
>   declare the Exception class to extend Exception as shown below, **the
>   compiler will insist** that the method that is being thrown should also
>   be in a caught in catch block.
>
> **The compiler gives the programmer two choices** when they call a method
>   that throws an Exception that must be caught: 
>   1. Add a try/catch in the code that is being call to catch the Exception 
>   2. Pass the Exception back on to the caller

So, you can see, the eclipse compiler enforces the programmer to handle the exception this way or the other. This is what I search also on Intellij.

---

Thanks!

Comment: IntelliJ and Eclipse are just development environments. They are nothing more than very fancy versions of Notepad. The Java compiler will always force you to handle a checked exception. Either catch it, or declare it as thrown in the method signature, or rethrow it wrapped as a runtime exception.

Comment: I am sorry. Actually I didn't managed to check your solution yet. I promise to do that asap and I will gladly select your answer I it answers my proolem.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ works in the same way as Window for checked exceptions : it requires that you handle (catch/throw) it.
But `File propertiesFile = new File(PROPS_FILE_PATH)` doesn't throw any checked exception. Look at the [constructor javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-).

Try with a statement that may throw a checked exception :

```
FileInputStream propertiesFile = new FileInputStream(PROPS_FILE_PATH);
```

> My main concern was to understand if there is a way to achieve the
>   same behavior of "detecting and alerting of exceptions" like in the
>   Eclipse IDE.

You could find the compilation error on the IDE both in the statement that causes it, the project view (the current class will be underlined in red) and in the problem view.
And the default intentions provided by IntelliJ (alt + Enter on the statement) will be to add the exception in the throw clause or to catch the exception.
In Eclipse you find the compilation error in the same places and the default quick fixes are the same.
So you should not be disorientated on IntelliJ. At least on this point. Note that on others you could be. Personally I am :)

About "alerting", the IntelliJ default way to run something is stricter than Eclipse : it fails fast.
The GhostCat answer addresses very well this point.  It may interest you.

Answer (score 1):

*Eclipse wouldn't build the project unless ...*

First of all: catching exceptions is a good thing. The "normal" mode of operation is: put a generated try/catch there, with a "TODO: should we catch, or do something else", and a print/dump of the exception at least. So that when you do start testing your code, you get to see exceptions.

Beyond that: actually eclipse is the IDE that (by default) continues to compile things even when it encounters errors. It even allows you to run method A in some class that has method B not compiling!

IntelliJ, on the other hand, will **stop** all compile activities upon hitting the first error. You actually have to *setup* your project to use the "eclipse" compiler style to get to the eclipse "continue compile after errors"!

Comment: Excellent side point : the IDE tolerance about running with compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling at anywhere at IntelliJ/Eclipse:

```
java.lang.Object
|
+--java.lang.Throwable
     |
     +--java.lang.Exception
     |     |
     |     +--java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
     |     |
     |     +--java.io.IOException
     |     |     |
     |     |     +--java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Here are the few other Checked Exceptions:-

```
*IOException
*ClassNotFoundException
*FileNotFoundException
```

so you need to check and handle bt try/catch locally or throws to parent before run: